Error deploying Node.js server on Render: MODULE_NOT_FOUND
I'm attempting to deploy my Node.js server on Render, but I'm encountering an error during deployment. The error seems to be related to a module not being found.
Error Log:
  requireStack: []
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/build/src/index.js'
  ^
  throw err;
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
==> Running 'node build/src/index.js'
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Node version 14.18.0 via /opt/render/project/src/package.json
}
  requireStack: []
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/build/src/index.js'
  ^
  throw err;
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
==> Running 'node build/src/index.js'
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Node version 14.18.0 via /opt/render/project/src/package.json
}
  requireStack: []
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47 {
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/build/src/index.js'
  ^
  throw err;
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:905
==> Running 'node build/src/index.js'
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Node version 14.18.0 via /opt/render/project/src/package.json
}
> all-chat-server@0.0.0 build /opt/render/project/src
==> Running 'npm run build'
==> Docs on specifying a bun version: https://render.com/docs/bun-version
==> Using Bun version 1.1.0 (default)
==> Docs on specifying a Node version: https://render.com/docs/node-version
==> Using Node version 14.18.0 via /opt/render/project/src/package.json

package.json
{
  "name": "all-chat-server",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "build/src/index.js",
  "types": "build/src/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "build/src"
  ],
  "license": "Apache-2.0",
  "keywords": [],
  "scripts": {
    "check-types": "tsc --noemit",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint src/**/*.ts",
    "clean": "gts clean",
    "fix": "gts fix",
    "start": "node ./build/src/index.js",
    "dev:tsc": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev --respawn --transpile-only src/index.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "husky install"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/bcryptjs": "^2.4.2",
    "@types/buffer-to-stream": "^1.0.3",
    "@types/connect-mongodb-session": "^2.4.3",
    "@types/cookie-parser": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/currency-formatter": "^1.5.1",
    "@types/express-session": "^1.17.4",
    "@types/fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.23",
    "@types/fs-extra": "^11.0.2",
    "@types/graphql-upload": "^8.0.11",
    "@types/html-pdf-node": "^1.0.0",
    "@types/jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.6",
    "@types/lodash": "^4.14.182",
    "@types/multer": "^1.4.7",
    "@types/multer-s3": "^2.7.12",
    "@types/node": "^14.11.2",
    "@types/node-cron": "^3.0.7",
    "@types/nodemailer": "^6.4.4",
    "@types/passport": "^1.0.7",
    "@types/passport-facebook": "^2.1.11",
    "@types/passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.11",
    "@types/passport-linkedin-oauth2": "^1.5.3",
    "@types/passport-local": "^1.0.34",
    "@types/pdf-parse": "^1.1.4",
    "@types/shortid": "0.0.29",
    "@types/validator": "^13.7.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.33.0",
    "eslint": "^7.32.0",
    "gts": "^3.1.0",
    "husky": "^8.0.3",
    "typescript": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@apollo/server": "^4.7.5",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.496.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-providers": "^3.496.0",
    "@aws-sdk/lib-storage": "^3.496.0",
    "@elastic/elasticsearch": "^8.10.0",
    "@ffmpeg-installer/ffmpeg": "^1.1.0",
    "@typegoose/typegoose": "^9.8.1",
    "@types/download": "^8.0.2",
    "@types/ws": "^8.5.3",
    "apollo-server-core": "^3.7.0",
    "apollo-server-express": "^3.7.0",
    "bcryptjs": "^2.4.3",
    "buffer-to-stream": "^1.0.0",
    "class-transformer": "^0.5.1",
    "class-validator": "^0.13.2",
    "cloudinary": "^2.1.0",
    "connect-mongodb-session": "^3.1.1",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.6",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "cpy-cli": "^4.2.0",
    "currency-formatter": "^1.5.9",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "docxtemplater": "^3.44.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.1",
    "download": "^8.0.0",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "express-async-errors": "^3.1.1",
    "express-session": "^1.17.3",
    "ffmpeg": "^0.0.4",
    "fluent-ffmpeg": "^2.1.2",
    "fs-extra": "^11.1.1",
    "graphql": "15.x",
    "graphql-mongoose-subscriptions": "^1.0.14",
    "graphql-passport": "^0.6.4",
    "graphql-type-json": "^0.3.2",
    "graphql-upload": "^13.0.0",
    "graphql-ws": "^5.10.1",
    "handlebars": "^4.7.7",
    "html-pdf-node": "^1.0.8",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "^9.0.2",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "mammoth": "^1.6.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.3",
    "mongoose": "^6.3.3",
    "multer": "^1.4.5-lts.1",
    "multer-s3": "^3.0.1",
    "netlify-lambda": "^2.0.16",
    "node-cron": "^3.0.2",
    "nodemailer": "^6.7.5",
    "openai": "^4.20.0",
    "passport": "^0.5.0",
    "passport-facebook": "^3.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-linkedin-oauth2": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-local": "^1.0.0",
    "pdf-parse": "^1.1.1",
    "pm2": "^5.3.1",
    "prettier": "^3.1.1",
    "puppeteer": "^22.0.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.13",
    "revai-node-sdk": "^3.6.2",
    "serverless-http": "^3.2.0",
    "shortid": "^2.2.16",
    "socket.io": "^4.5.1",
    "stripe": "^9.16.0",
    "ts-node-dev": "^1.1.8",
    "type-graphql": "^1.1.1",
    "typedi": "^0.10.0",
    "uuidv4": "^6.2.13",
    "ws": "^8.8.1",
    "xlsx": "^0.18.5"
  },
  "optionalDependencies": {
    "fsevents": "*"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "14.18.0"
  }
}

Here is the Render build command
npm install; npm run build

Here is Render start command
node build/src/index.js

Any insights into what might be causing this issue or how to resolve it would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

can you add the build command?

@Nahom Thank you for your response. This is my build command on Render: npm install; npm run build

Have you tried running npm start locally? Does it work?

@Nahom I got this error after running npm start: Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\User\Documents\Nodejs\all-chat-server\build\src\index.js'
I usually use this command to start my server locally: npm run dev

Time to go look in the build folder and find where index.js is located. Let's run npm run build first.

@Nahom I ran npm run build, But it didn't generate any build folder in my project directory
npm run build

all-chat-server@0.0.0 build
tsc
PS C:\Users\User\Documents\Nodejs\all-chat-server>


Let us continue this discussion in chat.


Error: Cannot find module '/opt/render/project/src/build/src/index.js'

The error tells me index.js is not located in src/build/src/index.js.
You need to build the project locally and find the location of index.js inside Typescript's output directory. You can get the output directory from your Typescript configuration.
After that, change the start command accordingly. If, for instance, it's located in ./dist, the start command must be node ./dist/index.js.
